# Read FORTRAN formatted numbers with Python

Tags: python, fortran

I have to read a data file that contains numbers formatted with (very) old FORTRAN style. A line of the file looks like this:

```
 4.500000+1 1.894719-3 4.600000+1 8.196721-3 4.700000+1 2.869539-3
```

The file (or large portion of it) contains these numbers in a fixed width format. The trouble with reading these numbers in Python is that there is no `E` in these numbers. Watch what happens:

```
>>> float('4.50000+1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 4.50000+1
```

I can write a parser to read this, but wanted to know if this has already be done. This is an old FORTRAN format so I thought perhaps someone had already figured it out. Does anyone know of a library to read numbers like this?

Comment: The simplest is probably to insert an `E` before the `+` or `-` and the Python have at the resulting string. (Assuming that's what it actually means).

Comment: never saw Fortran output like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
In [47]: strs="4.500000+1 1.894719-3 4.600000+1 8.196721-3 4.700000+1 2.869539-3"

In [48]: [float(x.replace("+","e+").replace("-","e-")) for x in strs.split()]

Out[48]: [45.0, 0.001894719, 46.0, 0.008196721, 47.0, 0.002869539]
```

Comment: This is what I was going to do, but was wondering if someone had already done something like this. Obviously there would need to be more features of the library to merit a full library, but this is a bare minimum.

Comment: @Jeremy check this out [A python function to convert FORTRAN formatted float strings into floats](https://gist.github.com/897137)

Comment: That function looks pretty good. It would require a minor modification as all of my numbers are formatted that way, not just the small ones.

Comment: What about negative numbers?   -4.5000+1

Comment: better see if you have negs and how they are formatted -- its plausible they would run into the next number w/ no space, assuming a fixed field width.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [Fortran Format Library for Python](https://github.com/brendanarnold/py-fortranformat) as follows,

```
>>> import fortranformat as ff
>>> reader = ff.FortranRecordReader('(6F13.7)')
>>> reader.read(' 4.500000+1 1.894719-3 4.600000+1 8.196721-3 4.700000+1 2.869539-3')
[45.0, 0.001894719, 46.0, 0.008196721, 47.0, 0.002869539]
```

This library has been extensively tested aginst Intel's ifort 9.1 compiler to match exactly some of the weirder FORTRAN textual IO.

Install using

```
pip install fortranformat
```

I should declare a bias since I wrote this library ...

Comment: The link to Bitbucket is broken. Is [this](https://github.com/brendanarnold/py-fortranformat] now the official repo?

Comment: Yes it is now https://github.com/brendanarnold/py-fortranformat

Answer (score 5):

You could use a regular expression to insert the "E"s before passing the numbers to `float`.

```
re.sub(r'(\d)([-+])', r'\1E\2', number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a system command to access AWK:

Note the escaping of the " characters inside `COMMAND`

```
import subprocess
COMMAND = "awk 'gsub(/D/,\"E\");{print}' epsc8.out > epsc8E.out"
subprocess.call(COMMAND, shell=True)
```