# Reading a file with Fortran formatted small floats, using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, fortran

I am trying to read a data file written by a Fortran program, in which every once in a while there is a very small float like `0.3299880-104`. The error message is:

```
>np.loadtxt(filename, usecols = (1,))

  File "/home/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 928, in loadtxt
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]

  File "/home/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 659, in floatconv
    return float(x)

ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0.3299880-104
```

Can I do something to make Numpy able to read this data file anyway?

Comment: Are you sure the number you're trying to read is `0.3299880e-104` and not just `0.3299880-104` ?

Comment: Personally I'd use a utility (I like `sed`) to modify numbers from `0.3299880-104` to `0.3299880e-104`.  I believe that Python itself can do that sort of thing, so you might want to write a routine to massage the file before reading it.

Comment: Possibly useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13274066.

Comment: @Shark - the number I am trying to read is without the `e`, just - `0.3299880-104`

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - I don't think it is a duplicate of the question 'Read FORTRAN formatted numbers with Python', as I am asking if there is a way to do it automatically with NumPy

Comment: I'm inclined to agree. It looks like you might develop a `converters` dictionary for `loadtxt` to handle this.  I'd suggest you put a little work into figuring that out and then pose a new more specific question. (Or a new answer to the linked question if you do figure it out)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **@agentp** mentioned in the comments, one approach would be to use the `converters=` argument to [`np.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) to insert the `e` characters before casting to float:

```
import numpy as np

# some example strings
strings = "0.3299880-104 0.3299880+104 0.3299880"

# create a "dummy file" (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11970414/1461210)
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO     # Python2
    f = StringIO(strings)
except ImportError:
    from io import BytesIO            # Python3
    f = BytesIO(strings.encode())

c = lambda s: float(s.decode().replace('+', 'e').replace('-', 'e-'))

data = np.genfromtxt(f, converters=dict(zip(range(3), [c]*3)))

print(repr(data))
# array([  3.29988000e-105,   3.29988000e+103,   3.29988000e-001])
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is helpful, but does not support negative values (`-0.3299880` is converted to `e-0.3299880`) or 2-digit exponents (`0.3299880E+10` is converted to `0.3299880Ee10`), which both do not make sense and would result in `nan` values in the numpy array.

Also, the number of columns in the file to read is hard-coded (it is 3 in this case).

It can be addressed as follows:

```
import re
import numpy as np

def read_fortran_data_file(file):
    # count the columns in the first row of data
    number_columns = np.genfromtxt(file, max_rows=1).shape[0]

    c = lambda s: float(re.sub(r"(\d)([\+\-])(\d)", r"\1E\2\3", s.decode()))

    # actually load the content of our file
    data = np.genfromtxt(file,
        converters=dict(zip(range(number_columns), [c] * number_columns)),)
```

**Testing**

`np.genfromtext` accepts filenames or arrays of strings as input.
For the demonstration I'll use the latter, but the above function works fine with filenames as input.

```
strings = [
    "0.3299880-104 0.3299880E+10 0.3299880 0.3299880+104 0.3299880E-10 -0.3299880"
]
read_fortran_data_file(strings)
## array([ 3.29988e-105,  3.29988e+009,  3.29988e-001,  3.29988e+103,
##         3.29988e-011, -3.29988e-001])
```

*Note on NaN values:*

When using `np.genfromtxt`, one must be careful with NaN values that would replace numbers that were not read properly, e.g. using the following assertion:

```
assert np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(data))==0, "data contains nan values"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not numpy, but I use the following regex and function:

```
import re

# convert d/D to e and add it if missing
fortregexp = re.compile(r'([\d.])[dD]?(((?<=[dD])[+-]?|[+-])\d)')
def fortran_float(num):
    num = fortregexp.sub(r'\1e\2', num)
    return float(num)

text = "0.3299880-104 0.3299880D+10 0.3299880 0.3299880+104 0.3299880E-10 -0.3299880"

nums = [fortran_float(i) for i in text.split()]

print(text)
print(nums)
```

which gives:

```
0.3299880-104 0.3299880D+10 0.3299880 0.3299880+104 0.3299880E-10 -0.3299880
[3.29988e-105, 3299880000.0, 0.329988, 3.29988e+103, 3.29988e-11, -0.329988]
```