# Fixing/reading wrong fortran output (missing the E in exponential notation) with Python

Tags: python, numpy, parsing, fortran

I have an output of a Fortran program that sometimes writes in exponential notation [without the E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004824/for-three-digit-exponents-fortran-drops-the-e-in-the-output). I can't fix the program at this point and I have to deal with the output.

Basically I'm trying to read the ASCII output file with [Numpy's `loadtxt` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), but it fails when it encounters the number `-0.1923856859-100` which is supposed to be written `-0.1923856859E-100`.

Is there any way to either read that properly with Numpy, or to easily re-write that file converting every instance where that happens to a proper notation?

Comment: This is not "wrong fortran output", it is standard Fortran output. And the "proper notation" is only proper for Python.

Comment: The minus (or plus) sign will always be immediately preceded by a digit.  You can run sed ten times (e.g., cat file | sed s/9-/9E-/g).  Or, you can write a python script with a regex that matches [0-9]- and [0-9]+, which then inserts [0-9]E- and [0-9]E+

Comment: @evets: "run sed 10 times" is silly. And `cat` is unnecessary. `sed -E 's/([0-9])([+-])/\1E\2/g' file`.

Comment: @rici, yeah, I know running sed ten times is silly.  Using python instead Fortran is also silly, to each his own.  I did sate that TomCHo could use a suitable regex within python.  I simply wasn't going to waste my time on trivialities.

Comment: Another option is to specify enough exponent digits so that 'E' is not suppressed.  This hasn't changed in 30 years, so F77 docs will do (or even those docs for bastard combinations of IBM360 fortran with F77).

Comment: Could try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545060/reading-a-file-with-fortran-formatted-small-floats-using-numpy